# How to link/merge an account created by custom token and phone auth in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Recently I am working with implementing new additional feature to sign in with custom token using firebase.

Before and now the app has an PhoneAuth authentication but in some cases the otp code is not arrived to users. Therefore we have to conclusion to add a custom token auth.
The problem is when backend generates a token and client is signing with this token, it creates a new account in firebase console. And how to link or merge them into one account? or is it possible to generate a token from an existing account in firebase and sign in with this account using generated token.

When I sign in through same phone with otp code it goes well, when I go with generated token it signed with new account.

Linking with other account providers like google, Facebook does not work for me. because for it users should be signed in.

Thanks